# Intercepting Alt+F4 in UAP

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm writing a UAP C#/XAML application, for the time being I'm interested in case when user runs my app in desktop environment (case when keyobard and mouse are available, the machine is running some version of Windows 10 not Windows 10 Mobile).

I want to intercept ALT+F4 in order to ask user a few important questions before they quit, like in for example notepad - when you have unsaved file and the notepad notifies you about this fact and asks if you want to save your work, quit without saving or go back to working with your file.

Is such a behaviour possible in Windows 10 UAP? I tried to play with Application.Suspending event and ExtendedExecutionSession, but it seems like before this event is fired the GUI thread is dead, and all I can do in this event's handler are operations not requiring user interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to intercept and stop events like this.

By the time your app is told it is suspending following a close event (alt+f4, cross clicked) you have 10 seconds (on desktop) to clear up and save state before you are completely terminated.

With universal apps, you shouldn't need a dialog asking them to save or not, just save state so next time they reopen you refresh the view to how it was before, or, think mail client, save their typings as a draft.  The guidance on Microsoft is, however, that if the user closes your app, assume they want you gone so don't restore state.

The only thing you can do for some extra processing is ask the OS for extended execution, though this isn't guaranteed and even if granted can be revoked with 1s notice to termination.  It's important to note that, even with extended execution granted, you app is not allowed any UI.

For more information on Windows 10 universal application lifecycle, I'd recommend watching the [Application Lifecycle](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/a-developer-s-guide-to-windows-10-12618?l=nXtix0pRB_5205095281) session on Microsoft Virtual Academy.